# Changing Number type to Text type when import csv by vba

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I got an import csv code below

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Dim xFileName As Variant
    Dim Rg As Range
    Dim xAddress As String
    xFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV File (*.csv), *.csv", , , , False)
    If xFileName = False Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    xAddress = Range("A1").Address
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" & xFileName, Range(xAddress))
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 65001
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Normally, it worked but when import csv but some kind of column that has start with 0 number, then excel treat that cell as Number and delete ( hide ) all 0 begin cell.

I've tried to add this script in but that not work.

```
ActiveSheet.NumberFormat = "@"
```

Comment: You can't format after import - you have to declare the column type as part of the import process. Use the text import wizard:  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-import-wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857   Or use Power Query if you know about that (and Google if not)

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for reply. So, i can't  format that after import the data, right ? I thought we can do that with vba. If we declare the column type before we import that, is that possible for me to import date again ( and result will hold 0 instead of delete it ) ?

Comment: It's easy enough to test that by manually formatting the column and then importing.  If that works then you're good to go: if not then you need to format the data as part of the import as described in the link I posted in my comment.

Comment: Thanks, i changed manually formatting the column and imported csv. But it still be deleted. i'm not sure, i tried to import csv manually instead of csv but still...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Have you tried format the destination field*

*Example*

*[QueryTable.TextFileColumnDataTypes property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.QueryTable.TextFileColumnDataTypes)*

> ```
> .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(xlTextFormat)
> ```

Comment: Thanks! My problem has been solve. The point here is, i have to duplicated all the column that i have to declare to 
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(xlTextFormat,xlTextFormat,xlTextFormat,....)

Comment: But, is that possible to declare all column instead of Array(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2......) ? Because i'm have to solve this problem with 100+ column

Comment: You could write a function which returns an array of `xlTextFormat` values of a specified size and call it like `.TextFileColumnDataTypes = TextFormatArray(100)`

Comment: @TimWilliams I did return in String like `.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(StringTypeVar)` but it has no reponse for this function. I find some reason, and i think that i can't count column while loading csv by vba