# Counting columns in querytable vba problem

Tags: excel, vba

I had a question about import and export csv before in this topic on link:
[Changing Number type to Text type when import csv by vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58195539/changing-number-type-to-text-type-when-import-csv-by-vba/)
The problem started when i added this code

```
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 2, _
                            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
```

Example: I have a csv like below:

> "a","b","c","e","f","g","h","i","j","k"
>
> "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"

When I export csv, output file be like this:

> "a","b","c","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","",""
>
> "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","",""

This script is declare that type of 12 columns is text type.
I have to solve with many kind of csv, and with this example, when i export it, the result csv has blank value in headers ( if the headers column in under 12 )

We can see here, when I declare the type of columns is in static way ( not in variable type of columns ). To do that, i have to get number of columns that import by QueryTable.

I've used this code to get number of columns:

```
ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" & xFileName, Range(xAddress)).ResultRange.Columns.Count
```

But this isn't work.

And this is my code on below:

```
Dim xFileName As Variant
Dim Rg As Range
Dim xAddress As String
xFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV File (*.csv), *.csv", , , , 
False)
If xFileName = False Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next
xAddress = Range("A1").Address

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" & xFileName, Range(xAddress))
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 65001
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 2, _
                                    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
                                    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
                                    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
                                    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
                                    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
                                    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
                                    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
                                    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
                                    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
                                    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
                                    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
                                    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, _
                                    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

I expect that i could declare columns in variable way like

```
Dim ExArr As Variant
Dim UsedColumns As Long
'
'This script to get number of Columns as UsedColumns
'
For i = 0 to UsedColumns
ExArr(i) = 2
Next i 
 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" & xFileName, Range(xAddress))
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(ExArr)
End With
```

Comment: Turn off screen updating, open the CSV using `workbooks.open`, count the number of columns (`Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count`), then close the workbook.  Now you know how many  2's you need in your array, so you can load the content via `QueryTables.Add` using an array of the correct size.

Comment: EDIT - I see you already have that approach at the bottom of your post, so why not just do that?